# #P-complete with decision P

Tags: counting-complexity

We know that an NP complete problem with a parsimonious reduction but a many one reduction is candidate problem for NP complete problem not being #P hard.

1. Likewise is there a possible classification of which P-complete or NL-complete or in general P problems are likely to have counting problems #P-hard and not in #P-hard?

Answer (score 5):

Look here: "[The Complexity of Counting Functions with Easy Decision Version](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11821069_64)"

by Zachos and Pagourtzis.

> We investigate the complexity of counting problems that belong to the complexity class #P and have an easy decision version. These problems constitute the class #PE which has some well-known representatives such as #Perfect Matchings, #DNF-Sat, and NonNegative Permanent. An important property of these problems is that they are all #P-complete, in the Cook sense, while they cannot be #P-complete in the Karp sense unless P = NP.